# How to build a script for fasttext tuning with a shell script

Tags: shell, fasttext

I want to test the accuracy of 2000 categories with the trained model. I don't want to do it manually. That is too much work.I want to write a script to implement the following functions，I'm going to loop through these commands：

```
./fasttext model.bin data/data_test/__lable__00001 >> log_label__00001 ... ./fasttext model.bin data/data_test/__lable__02000 >> log_label__02000 ...，
```

For each piece of command I need to change the test data path and file name of the log written, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` you can do

```
for nr in {00001..02000}; do
   ./fasttext model.bin data/data_test/__lable__${nr} >> log_label__${nr}
done
```

When `{00001..02000}` doesn't work in your shell, try something like

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt 2000 ]; do
   (( i++ ))
   printf -v nr "%05d" $i
   ./fasttext model.bin data/data_test/__lable__${nr} >> log_label__${nr}
done
```